# Neo4jRB: updating node data?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Looking at ActiveNode's [`persistence.rb`](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/0888cd3132792802b7983e1047f4bf07bfc49d38/lib/neo4j/active_node/persistence.rb), it seems like there's no `update()` or equivalent. How does one update the data of a particular node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` comes from `Neo4j::Shared::Persistence`, not ActiveNode. You can find it [here](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/lib/neo4j/shared/persistence.rb#L114).

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'update'` when I call  `update` on an ActiveNode object — what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the full error? `undefined method 'update' for`... what kind of object?

Comment: I was expecting `update` to be a static method and was calling it on the ActiveRel class, like ActiveRecord's interface. Now correctly calling it on the instance. All good, thank you!